# Add row color to odd row in repeater

Tags: html, css, repeater

Hi guys got a little design issue here.

I got this repeater that contains this table

```
<table class="Library">              
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 170px; padding-left: 30px; height: 50px;"><%#RemoveTimeInDate(Eval("ValidTo").ToString())%></td>
        <td style="width: 449px; height: 50px;"><a style="color: black" href="Info.aspx?id=<%# Eval("Id") %>"> <%# Eval("Title") %></a></td>
        <td style="width: 2px; padding-left: 3px; height: 50px;">></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
 .Library {
     font-size: 12px;
 }
 .Library a {
     color: #007583;
 }
 .Library a:visited {
     color: #007583;
 }
 .Library tr:nth-child(Odd) {
     background-color: #FFFFCC;
 }
```

To get this to work i haft to add another tablerow for the row colors to change.Is there a way to add different row colors when there is only 1  in the repeater

Comment: Your code seems to work: http://codepen.io/baxeico/pen/kIoyp maybe I didn't understood the problem

Comment: @baxeico OP wants other color when there is only one row. al-web, I think this is possible while generating template only you should count the rows and apply classes/styles as per the no. of rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one row in a table, you can style it using the [:only-child css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child).

You can also combine the use of :only-child and :nth-child as I did in this [example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/baxeico/pen/kIoyp), to style both tables with just one row and tables with multiple rows, even with different colors for the first row in multiple rows case and the only row in the single row case. Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.Library tr:nth-child(Odd) {
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
.Library tr:nth-child(Even) {
    background-color: #CCFFFF;
}
.Library tr:only-child {
    background-color: #CCFFFF;
}
```

Note that the :only-child selector must be after the :nth-child(Odd) one, to have precedence over it in the case of tables with a single row.

Comment: nice, I was going to add javascript code. I wasn't aware of this. thanks :)

Comment: Still getting the same color for all my rows

Comment: What browser are you using? Did you tried my example on Codepen?

Answer (score 0):

I dont get what you need exactly but you can use :nth-child(even) to start coloring from the first row.

[here is the w3 example of even odd nth child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child_odd_even)

Comment: To problem is: I have only one row in the repeater. When i have tr:nth-child(Odd) all my rows will be colored. WHen i have tr:nth-child(Even) none of my tables are colored.